# Golang Windows Service - stop after graceful shutdown of application

Tags: go, windows-services

I have been building a web service with net/http. The small web services will be started as a windows services like this way: https://github.com/Technololist/golang-http-windows-service/blob/master/websvc.go

It seems that the services is going to terminate the web service when a “stop” is called via “services” on windows.
I would like to wait until the web services and all underlying functions have been finished and then stop the service.

As suggested by @Jory Geerts I have a little bit changed my code.

main.go:

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "path/filepath"
    "strings"
    "time"

    "golang.org/x/sys/windows/svc"
    "golang.org/x/sys/windows/svc/eventlog"
    "golang.org/x/sys/windows/svc/mgr"
)

type winservice struct{}

type ErrorMessage struct {
    message, severity string
    eventId           int
}

var IsFirstRun bool = true
var elog *eventlog.Log
var eventidInformation uint32 = 1001
var eventidWarning uint32 = 1002
var eventidError uint32 = 1003
var DebugMode bool = false

const svcName = "PerformanceDataExporter4"

const svcDisplayName = "Performance-Data Exporter 4"

func main() {
    //fmt.Println("Funktion main angesprungen")
    elog, _ = eventlog.Open(svcName)
    defer elog.Close()

    isIntSess, err := svc.IsAnInteractiveSession()
    if err != nil {
        elog.Error(eventidInformation, "Error checking for interactive session")
        os.Exit(2)
    }

    if !isIntSess {
        runService(svcName)
        return
    }

    if len(os.Args) < 2 {
        usage("No parameter!")
    }

    cmd := strings.ToLower(os.Args[1])
    switch cmd {
    case "install":
        err = installService(svcName, svcDisplayName)
    case "remove":
        err = controlService(svcName, svc.Stop, svc.Stopped)
        if err == nil {
            err = removeService(svcName)
        }
    case "start":
        err = startService(svcName)
    case "stop":
        err = controlService(svcName, svc.Stop, svc.Stopped)
    case "debug":
        DebugMode = true
        err = startService(svcName)
    case "readmode":
        StartExporterTest()

    default:
        usage(fmt.Sprintf("Unexpected command '%s'", cmd))
    }
    if err != nil {
        var er *ErrorMessage
        if errors.As(err, &er) {
            writeEventLog(er.severity, er.message, uint(er.eventId))
        }
    }
}

func usage(errmsg string) {
    fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "%s\n\n"+
        "Usage: %s <command>\n"+
        "        where <command> is one of\n"+
        "        install, remove, start, stop, debug or readmode.\n",
        errmsg, os.Args[0])
    os.Exit(2)
}

func writeEventLog(severity string, message string, eventId uint) {
    switch severity {
    case "error":
        elog.Error(uint32(eventidError), message)
    case "warning":
        elog.Warning(uint32(eventidWarning), message)
    case "information":
        elog.Info(uint32(eventidInformation), message)
    default:
        elog.Info(uint32(eventidInformation), message)
    }
}

func (e *ErrorMessage) Error() string {
    return e.message
}

func runService(name string) error {
    run := svc.Run
    if err := run(name, &winservice{}); err != nil {
        return &ErrorMessage{message: fmt.Sprintf("Service '%s' got an error: %v", name, err), severity: "error"}
    }
    return nil
}

func (m *winservice) Execute(args []string, r <-chan svc.ChangeRequest, changes chan<- svc.Status) (ssec bool, errno uint32) {
    const cmdsAccepted = svc.AcceptStop | svc.AcceptShutdown | svc.AcceptPauseAndContinue
    changes <- svc.Status{State: svc.StartPending}
    fasttick := time.Tick(500 * time.Millisecond)
    slowtick := time.Tick(2 * time.Second)
    tick := fasttick
    changes <- svc.Status{State: svc.Running, Accepts: cmdsAccepted}
loop:
    for {
        select {
        case <-tick:
            StartExporterTest()
        case c := <-r:
            switch c.Cmd {
            case svc.Interrogate:
                changes <- c.CurrentStatus
                time.Sleep(100 * time.Millisecond)
                changes <- c.CurrentStatus
            case svc.Stop, svc.Shutdown:
                writeEventLog("information", "Exporter HTTP-Server wird beendet", uint(eventidInformation))
                shutdownCtx, shutdownRelease := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 10*time.Second)
                defer shutdownRelease()
                if err := HttpServer.Shutdown(shutdownCtx); err != nil {
                    writeEventLog("information", fmt.Sprintf("HTTP shutdown error: %v", err), uint(eventidInformation))
                }
                writeEventLog("information", "Graceful shutdown complete.", uint(eventidInformation))
                break loop
            case svc.Pause:
                changes <- svc.Status{State: svc.Paused, Accepts: cmdsAccepted}
                tick = slowtick
            case svc.Continue:
                changes <- svc.Status{State: svc.Running, Accepts: cmdsAccepted}
                tick = fasttick
            default:
                writeEventLog("warning", fmt.Sprintf("Unexpected control request #%d", c), uint(eventidWarning))
            }
        }
    }
    changes <- svc.Status{State: svc.StopPending}
    return
}

func exePath() (string, error) {
    prog := os.Args[0]
    p, err := filepath.Abs(prog)
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }
    fi, err := os.Stat(p)
    if err == nil {
        if !fi.Mode().IsDir() {
            return p, nil
        }
        return "", &ErrorMessage{message: fmt.Sprintf("'%s' is an directory", p), severity: "error"}
    }
    if filepath.Ext(p) == "" {
        p += ".exe"
        fi, err := os.Stat(p)
        if err == nil {
            if !fi.Mode().IsDir() {
                return p, nil
            }
        }
    }
    return "", err
}

func installService(name, desc string) error {
    writeEventLog("information", fmt.Sprintf("Service '%v' (Displayname: '%v') will be installed.", svcName, svcDisplayName), uint(eventidInformation))
    exepath, err := exePath()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    m, err := mgr.Connect()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer m.Disconnect()
    s, err := m.OpenService(name)
    if err == nil {
        s.Close()
        return &ErrorMessage{message: fmt.Sprintf("Service '%v' (Displayname: '%v') already exists", svcName, svcDisplayName), severity: "error"}
    }
    s, err = m.CreateService(name, exepath, mgr.Config{DisplayName: desc}, "is", "auto-started")
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer s.Close()
    err = eventlog.InstallAsEventCreate(name, eventlog.Error|eventlog.Warning|eventlog.Info)
    if err != nil {
        s.Delete()
        return &ErrorMessage{message: fmt.Sprintf("'Event log Source' could not be created: %s", err), severity: "error"}
    }
    return nil
}

func removeService(name string) error {
    writeEventLog("information", fmt.Sprintf("Service '%v' (Displayname: '%v') will be removed.", svcName, svcDisplayName), uint(eventidInformation))
    m, err := mgr.Connect()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer m.Disconnect()
    s, err := m.OpenService(name)
    if err != nil {
        return &ErrorMessage{message: fmt.Sprintf("Accessing service '%v' (Displayname: '%v') not possible: %v", svcName, svcDisplayName, err), severity: "error"}
    }
    defer s.Close()
    err = s.Delete()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    err = eventlog.Remove(name)
    if err != nil {
        return &ErrorMessage{message: fmt.Sprintf("'Event log Source' could not be removed: %s", err), severity: "error"}
    }

    return nil
}

func startService(name string) error {
    writeEventLog("information", fmt.Sprintf("Service '%v' (Displayname: '%v') will be started.", svcName, svcDisplayName), uint(eventidInformation))
    m, err := mgr.Connect()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer m.Disconnect()
    s, err := m.OpenService(name)
    if err != nil {
        return &ErrorMessage{message: fmt.Sprintf("Accessing service '%v' (Displayname: '%v') not possible: %v", svcName, svcDisplayName, err), severity: "error"}
    }
    defer s.Close()
    err = s.Start("is", "manual-started")
    if err != nil {
        return &ErrorMessage{message: fmt.Sprintf("Service '%v' (Displayname: '%v') could not be started: %v", svcName, svcDisplayName, err), severity: "error"}
    }
    return nil
}

func controlService(name string, c svc.Cmd, to svc.State) error {
    m, err := mgr.Connect()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer m.Disconnect()
    s, err := m.OpenService(name)
    if err != nil {
        return &ErrorMessage{message: fmt.Sprintf("Accessing service '%v' (Displayname: '%v') not possoble: %v", svcName, svcDisplayName, err), severity: "error"}
    }
    defer s.Close()
    status, err := s.Control(c)
    if err != nil {
        return &ErrorMessage{message: fmt.Sprintf("Error for command 'control=%d' to service '%v' (Displayname: '%v'): %v", c, svcName, svcDisplayName, err), severity: "error"}
    }
    timeout := time.Now().Add(10 * time.Second)
    for status.State != to {
        if timeout.Before(time.Now()) {
            return &ErrorMessage{message: fmt.Sprintf("Trying to send service '%v' (Displayname: '%v') to status 'state=%d' got timeout", svcName, svcDisplayName, to), severity: "error"}
        }
        time.Sleep(300 * time.Millisecond)
        status, err = s.Query()
        if err != nil {
            return &ErrorMessage{message: fmt.Sprintf("Cannot request actual status of service '%v' (Displayname: '%v'): %v", svcName, svcDisplayName, err), severity: "error"}
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

perflibtest.go

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "time"

    "github.com/prometheus/client_golang/prometheus"
    "github.com/prometheus/client_golang/prometheus/promhttp"
)

var HttpServerTest = &http.Server{}

type WindowsOsCollectorTest struct {
    hostname string
}

func (collector *WindowsOsCollectorTest) Describe(ch chan<- *prometheus.Desc) {
    prometheus.DescribeByCollect(collector, ch)
}

func (collector *WindowsOsCollectorTest) Collect(ch chan<- prometheus.Metric) {
    var description *prometheus.Desc
    writeEventLog("error", "Request startet", uint(eventidError))

    time.Sleep(time.Second * 10)

    metricNameTest := "PerValue_Number1"
    helpTextTest := "Helptext för Perfvalue_Number1"
    description = prometheus.NewDesc(metricNameTest, helpTextTest, nil, nil)
    ch <- prometheus.MustNewConstMetric(description, prometheus.GaugeValue, float64(5))
    writeEventLog("error", "Request finished", uint(eventidError))
}

func NewWindowsOsCollectorTest(host string) *WindowsOsCollectorTest {
    return &WindowsOsCollectorTest{
        hostname: host,
    }
}

func StartExporterTest() {
    if IsFirstRun {
        IsFirstRun = false
        HttpServerTest := &http.Server{Addr: ":8089"}
        reg := prometheus.NewRegistry()
        err := reg.Register(NewWindowsOsCollectorTest("hostname"))
        if err != nil {
            elog.Error(eventidError, fmt.Sprintf("Register 'NewWindowsOsCollector' error: %v", err))
        }
        http.Handle("/metrics", promhttp.HandlerFor(reg, promhttp.HandlerOpts{MaxRequestsInFlight: 5}))
        go func() {
            if err := HttpServerTest.ListenAndServe(); err != http.ErrServerClosed {
                writeEventLog("error", fmt.Sprintf("HTTP server error: %v", err), uint(eventidError))
            } else if err == http.ErrServerClosed {
                writeEventLog("information", fmt.Sprintf("HTTP server got shutdown command: %v", err), uint(eventidInformation))
            }
        }()
    }
}
```

If the service is started and I send the stop command directly after the start command the webservice is stopped after the "time.sleep" is finished.
If the service has been started some time ago, I refresh the website and stop the service, the "time.sleep" is interrupted. That's a little bit confusing and I don't know why this happens.

The next problem is if I stop the service directly after its start I get an windows error that the service could not be stopped. That's correct because it is waiting for "time.sleep" to end.
Maybe I need some additional code at the "case svc.Stop, svc.Shutdown:" to check if the webservice is active or not and give windows a feedback.

Do you have an idea or suggestions how to get the code working?
I think I am missing some knowledge about windows service and how it works in Golang.

Thank you,
Jens

Comment: It clearly indicates where the stop is received, at which point you could do your graceful shutdown (or any other needed cleanup) before returning. Do you have a more specific question about this? What have you tried?

Comment: Hi Adrian,

I think you talk about the loop-for „case svc.Stop“ area.
This would be the place for the code for the graceful shutdown I think.
I have problems to implement the graceful shutdown at this point. When I put a „time.sleep“ of 15 seconds during requests and stop the service, the request will killed directly.
Do you have some hints how to implement a graceful shutdown for „net/http“ server at this part of the script?

Comment: Hi Adrian, I change my initial request and gave you all the code that behaves not like expected with some additional informations.

Answer (score 1):

The example code uses [`http.ListenAndServe()`](https://github.com/Technololist/golang-http-windows-service/blob/master/websvc.go#L268C13-L268C47), which wraps some functionality in such a way that you cannot close the server from your code. If instead, you create a `http.Server{}` yourself and call its `ListenAndServe()` function from inside `runApp()`, you can call the `Shutdown(context.Context)` function of your `http.Server{}` in the `case svc.Stop, svc.Shutdown:` part of the code. Once you called `http.Server{}.Shutdown()`, it will stop accepting new requests, but requests that are already being processed will be completed (if needed, you can pass a context with a timeout to forcefully abort requests that take *too long* to finish).

Comment: Hi Jory,

I will give it a try and tell you, if I got it working.

Thanks,
Jens

Comment: Hi Jory,
I changed my initial post and pasted all my code over there. The shutdown now works some times. That's aliitle bit confusing. If I send the stop directly after the start the script is waiting for the "time.sleep" to end. If I start the service a little bit later the "time.sleep" will be interrupted and the script is stopped immediately. Do you have any idea why this happens?
The next problem is if I stop the service directly after its start I get an windows error that the service could not be stopped. That's correct because it is waiting for "time.sleep" to end.